# Adding Separate Main for Landscape Mode

Tags: android

Working as an .NET developer since I know myself and just bought an Android phone and think have to learn something new would not hurt me whatsoever, start reading one of those reference development books "Hello Android" and just read 50 page in a hour and like the system more than anything I know

Now I got a problem, under UI development topic it says I am able to develop two UI one for portrait and other for landscape besides, it says those two main.xml files are separated by their suffix so If I want to support two mode have to have two main.xml files one of them would be separated from other with -land suffix. But not able to create a new main UI with land suffix please could you show me how could I able to create a new main.xml with -land suffix under Eclipse. If you explain with screen shots it could be much more expressive.

Comment: What do you mean by the -land suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  for reference.

But what you actually do is create a new folder under your res. Called layout-land for landscape layouts. And then have the layout main in that folder.

See this catalogue structure:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

the name of your landscape layout file will be main.xml, same as your portrait file, but it will be in the directory `res/layout-land` instead of simply `res/layout` where your portrait file will be. hope this helps and was simple enough without screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder **layout-land** in res folder and put the landscape main.xml in it